# How stop page breaks and move the methodology section on to same page as my text?

Tags: packages, programming

[image]

This is my main driver file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
\title{Predicting the future behaviour of SARS-CoV-2 in Ethiopia and Australia using a deterministic SEIRDV model}}
\author{Subject: Biology \\ Word count: 3980}
\date{September 5 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\include{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\include{Introduction}
\include{Methodology}
\include{Raw data}
\include{Processed data}
\include{limitations}
\include{Appendix}
\include{References}
\end{document}
```

This is my methodology code

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Overview of SEIRDV model}
\begin{doublespace}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass with which options do you use?

Comment: Each `\include` directive creates a pagebreak. If you don't want page breaks, use `\input` instead of `\include`.  E.g., assuming the file in question is named `Methodology.tex`, replace `\include{Methodology}` with `\input Methodology`.

Comment: I changed \include{Methodology} with \input Methodology in my preamble but it didn't change anything